# Devise redirect after signin with username in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm struggling with getting devise to redirect to a user's profile page after signin. My routes file looks like this:

```
get "profiles/index"

get "users/index"

get "users/show"

authenticated :user do
 root :to => 'home#index'
end
root :to => "home#index"
devise_for :users
resources :users
scope ":username", :as => "user" do
 match '/', :to => 'profiles#index'
end
```

I would like it to redirect to /myusername which the user's profile page.  Thanks for your guys' help.

Comment: I know you have already accepted an answer but I would just like to point out 2 things. First, your routes shouldn't be like that. The root should always be at the end of the file. And second and most important of all, you should always search for a gem's documentation as it usually explains a lot of problems you might encounter. Here's a list of wiki pages about devise: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages . And here is the page that answers your specific problem: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-or-sign-out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the sign in redirect you can override the after_sign_in_path_for method by adding a new SessionsController as so:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController  

  #after_sign_in_path_for is called by devise
  def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
   "/users/#{user.username}" #adjust the returned path as needed
  end  

end
```

As Ashikata mentioned you need to change the devise routing to the following if you're changing the session controller.

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => 'sessions' }
```

---

Alternatively, adding that modified after_sign_in_path_for method to your application controller should do the trick.

Comment: You should also mention that you have to edit the routes file so that it uses the newly created controller. `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => 'sessions' }`